# elementary python question about type conversion

Tags: python, types

I have question after trying the code below. I expected the code to print 1 2 3 but this code print 1.1,2.2,3.3. could anyone explain why it is for beginner?

```
list1=[1.1,2.2,3.3]

for i in list1:
    i=int(i)

for i in list1:
    print(i)
```

why this code print

```
1.1
2.2
3.3
```

but not

```
1
2
3
?
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: or some Python online course concerning lists  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for i in list1:
    i=int(i)
```

Changing `i` in the loop has no effect on the list.  On each loop iteration, `i` is set to the next element of `list1`.  You can assign anything you want to it without affecting the list.  It's no different from:

```
i = list1[ix]
i = 123
```

This clearly won't affect `list1`, for the exact same reason.

If you want to change the list, you can do:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i] = int(list1[i])
```

This will modify the elements of `list1`.

Another approach would be:

```
list1 = [int(i) for i in list1]
```

This doesn't modify the list referenced by `list1`, but it instead creates a *new* list, then assigns it to `list1`.  Any other references to the old `list` will be unchanged, but `list1` will now reference the new list which contains the changed values.